# fetching disting row from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I want to include search feature in my site.

I want to allow search based on user name, city, college/school name, employeer.
name is mandatory and others are optional field.
I am having following tables

```
users(id,fname,lname,city)
profile_pic(id,pic,userid)//userid from users(id) 
educationdetail(eduid,school,userid)//userid from users(id) 
employment(empid.employeer,userid)//userid from users(id)
```

in profile_pic per user is having only one picture;
in educationdetail user can add multiple school college details
in employment user can add multiple work details

for search purpose I am using following query:

```
    SELECT distinct s.id, s.fname, s.lname,pr.pic
     FROM users as s LEFT JOIN profile_pic as pr 
     on s.id = pr.userid
     LEFT JOIN educationdetail as edu
     on s.id=edu.userid
     LEFT JOIN  employment as emp
     on s.id=emp.userid
     where s.fname like '%m%' and s.lname like '%%%' and s.city like '%%%'
```

which is giving proper details

but when including few paramenters it is not showing any result

```
     SELECT distinct s.id, s.fname, s.lname,pr.pic
     FROM users as s LEFT JOIN profile_pic as pr 
     on s.id = pr.userid
     LEFT JOIN educationdetail as edu
     on s.id=edu.userid
     LEFT JOIN  employment as emp
     on s.id=emp.userid
     where s.fname like '%m%' and s.lname like '%%%' and s.city like '%%%'
     and  edu.school='%%%' and emp.employeer='%%%';
```

showing

```
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `LIKE '%%%'`?

Comment: '%pattern%'  here '%%%' means any pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use `OR`, then when searching for patter use `LIKE` not `=`

```
and  edu.school LIKE '%' and emp.employeer LIKE '%';
```

**UPDATE 1**

the reason it doesn't return any value is because the query is searching for the value of `%%%` in the field `edu.school` which doesn't exist.

Comment: you are correct but now also  and  edu.school LIKE '%' and emp.employeer LIKE '%' is not showing results

Comment: what is the value you are trying to search?

Comment: s.fname like '%man%' and rest are like '%' it it not fetching data but 1 query as mentioned in question is showing all related data

Comment: Is it  due to no education and employement details stored for other users?

Comment: where s.fname like '%m%' and s.lname like '%%%' and s.city like '%%%'
     Or  (edu.school like '%' or emp.employeer like '%')

Comment: Yes problem was that, I tried with or it is showing result edu.school like '%' or emp.employeer like '%' is also showing names other than %m%. I am going to use AND insted of OR. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [`ESCAPE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) keyword, to specify an escaping character, when trying to search for a reserved wildcards with the predicate `LIKE` in your case, if you want to search for the value `%`, use:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%|%%' ESCAPE '|' -- Or any escape character.
```

instead of just:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%%%'
```